# Date and Time field type values

Tags: custom-field-types

I am trying to customize the Date and Time field type to show only in multiples of 30. However, the default is only in the multiples of 5. Is there a way to change that to multiples of 30. Example, the time drop down gives the hour and minutes. The minutes is in 5, 10, 15, 20 etc. But, my requirement is to show 00 or 30. Please suggest.

Note: I am a beginner and not looking at coding the requirement. Please help.

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to hide it from the New or Edit form, you could add a content editor webpart to New/edit form and use jquery to hide unwanted minutes. If you have a custom script referenced from your master page, you could add it there instead.

Change 'MyDateColumn' to your column name.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("select[id^='MyDateColumn'][id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes'] > option").each(function () {
    var optVal = $(this).val();
    if (optVal != '00' && optVal != '30') {
        $(this).remove();
    }
 }); 
});
```

Another option is to create your own CustomFieldType control but it requires server side coding.